# Firestore/Firebase permissions denied using onDisconnect()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In this Javascript, everything is working except the `presenceRef.onDisconnect().set('no more');` statement, which generates **PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied** in my console.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
    if (user){
        uid=user.uid;

        db.collection('user').doc(uid).set({
            custnum: parseInt(custnum),
            email: email,
            password: password,
            screenname: screenname,
            admin: parseInt(admin),
            uid: uid
        })
        .then(function(){
            var docpath='/user/'+uid+'/email';

            var presenceRef=firebase.database().ref(docpath);

            presenceRef.onDisconnect().set('no more');
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log('Error writing document: ' + error);
        });
    } else {
        db.collection('user').doc(uid).delete({
        })
        .then(function(){
            //success
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log('Error writing document: ' + error);
        });

        uid='';
    }
});
```

In the Rules tab when I am connected to this URL:

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/[Project Name]/database/firestore/rules

...I have everything opened up, as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I can use **.set** to write to the database. Why can I not use **onDisconnect()** to .set a different value? **.db** refers to a **firebase.firestore()** connection. Is there something going on here between Firebase and Firestore that I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`onDisconnect()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect) is a method for the realtime database and not Firestore, it allows you to write or clear data when your client disconnects from the Database server.

Therefore if you meant to [use it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence), then change the rules for the realtime database to the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

only use those rules in development.

Comment: Yes, that removes my error. Is it not possible to remove data from Firestore on disconnect then?

Comment: firestore caches the data automatically for you https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline if you don't have internet and want to change, you can using normal `set()` when you go online again it should sync with the database

Comment: I was hoping to use onDisconnect to generate a list of users who are actively logged into my app at any given time. That is what I was able to do with another app I wrote using Firebase (years ago). Not possible with Firestore?

Comment: For example, if you're building an app like a social network or deploying a fleet of IoT devices, you could use this information to display a list of friends that are online and free to chat, or sort your IoT devices by "last seen."

Cloud Firestore doesn't natively support presence, but you can leverage other Firebase products to build a presence system. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence

Comment: Not really what I wanted to hear, but thank you. I'll see what I can do.